# Magento - How to create an Adminhtml page with grid table getting data from custom MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1.

Right now i'm working on a custom extension for Magento and i need to know how to get the data from a custom MySQL table into a table in custom admin panel page.

I've already added a custom page in the admin panel, here it is:

[image]

Here is the code of this page /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/vivasindustries/smsnotification/about.phtml:

```
<h2> Hi there</h2>
This is new custom page where i must add a grid table!
```

In this page i want to add a grid table like this one:

[image]

This is just an example of what kind of table i need.
In this table there must be in first time so i can understand how the things work only 3 cells - `Receiver`,`Phone` and `Date` which is fetching data from my custom MySQL table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`.

Here is a picture from the phpMyAdmin so you can see the structure of the table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`:

[image]

So at final i want to say that i want this data to be snown in my custom admin page a grid table..

Please help me out to make this thing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you look at an existing block class, such as the Catalog -> Manage Products one:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php
```

You can copy that file to your own module, and rename the class to [Namespace]_[Module]*Block*[BlockName]

You'll probably want to change the code in the _prepareCollection and _prepareColumns methods.

As well as creating your own model inside your module to retrieve the data from the database, you might want to look at keeping the getCollection() method by inheriting certain classes, not sure which class you would need to inherit though.